# How to draw Spraling text using canvas and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a spiraling text in canvass. so far, all I can do was a circled text. can someone help me with my code? what do i need to change to make it spiral instead of circle? here is my code.

```js
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillTextCircle = function(text,x,y,radius,startRotation){
   var numRadsPerLetter = 2*Math.PI / text.length;
   this.save();
   this.translate(x,y);
   this.rotate(startRotation);

   for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
      this.save();
      this.rotate(i*numRadsPerLetter);
      this.fillText(text[i],0,-radius);
      this.restore();
   }
   this.restore();
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "bold 30px Serif";
ctx.fillTextCircle("this is a sample of spiraling text. you can see more examples as we go on",150,150,75,Math.PI / 2);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
   CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillTextCircle = function(text,x,y,radius,startRotation){
   var numRadsPerLetter = 2*Math.PI / text.length;
   this.save();
   this.translate(x,y);
   this.rotate(startRotation);

   for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
      this.save();
      this.rotate(i*numRadsPerLetter);
      this.fillText(text[i],0,-radius);
      this.restore();
   }
   this.restore();
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "bold 30px Serif";
ctx.fillTextCircle("this is a sample of spiraling text. you can see more examples as we go on",150,150,75,Math.PI / 2);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to increase or decrease the radius per char.

```
this.save();
this.translate(x,y);
this.rotate(startRotation);

for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
  // ...
  radius += 0.5;   // here arbitrary
  // ...
}
```

In addition, the angle delta must be based on current circle circumference and letter width. This means rotation must happen after the char has been drawn:

```
var rot = ctx.measureText(text[i]).width / (Math.PI * radius * 2) * Math.PI*2;
```

This calculates the circumference in number of pixels. Then it divides the current char width on it to get a normalized value. The normalized value is then multiplied with a full circle langth based on radius to get angle the next rotation has to add to get to a new position.

If this step isn't performed the letters may overlap of have too wide gap depending on the radius.

You can also remove a pair of `save()`/`restore()` by using relative rotation based on the previous calculated delta, so the new function becomes:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillTextCircle = function(text,x,y,radius,startRotation){
   this.save();
   this.translate(x,y);
   this.rotate(startRotation);

   for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
     var rot = ctx.measureText(text[i]).width / (Math.PI * radius * 2) * Math.PI*2;
      this.fillText(text[i],0, -radius);
      this.rotate(rot);
     radius += 0.5;
   }
   this.restore();
}
```

In the update below I use an arbitrary value to increase radius. Also here you can calculate it more accurately by obtaining the height of the char, divide it on a full circle based on radius, then increment with this. Add a small delta for "line"-height.

```js
  CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillTextCircle = function(text,x,y,radius,startRotation){
   var numRadsPerLetter = 2*Math.PI / text.length;
   this.save();
   this.translate(x,y);
   this.rotate(startRotation);

   for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
      this.save();
      this.rotate(i*numRadsPerLetter);
      this.fillText(text[i],0,-radius);
      this.restore();
   }
   this.restore();
}

CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillTextCircle = function(text,x,y,radius,startRotation){
   this.save();
   this.translate(x,y);
   this.rotate(startRotation);

   for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
     var rot = ctx.measureText(text[i]).width / (Math.PI * radius * 2) * Math.PI*2;
      this.fillText(text[i],0, -radius);
      this.rotate(rot);
     radius += 0.5;
   }
   this.restore();
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "bold 30px Serif";
ctx.fillTextCircle("this is a sample of spiraling text. you can see more examples as we go on",150,150,75,Math.PI / 2);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi. @K3N thank you for your reply. I'm new to canvas with javascript. you are so kind to help me improve my code and explain why and where to put things. Thank and god bless! I'll be having A+ now in my subject. your a life saver!